# When declarativeWebRequest will be available to stable channel

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know when declarativeWebRequest API will be moved from dev channel? It is available since version 21 (or 22), now dev version is 23 and beta channel don't have this API implemented.
I wrote an application witch use this API and I would like to know when finally It will be released.

Answer (score -3):

declarativeWebRequest API is now available in beta channel. It should be soon in stable channel...